# LEFT JOIN returns Not unique table/alias and Unknown column in 'on clause

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have PHP website with a table that prints out search results from a MySQL database via form with an input box. I use this SQL syntax and it works fine. I can search in one filed to get results from location.room_name and users.user_name:

**SELECT:**

```
SELECT computers.*, location.room_name AS location
FROM computers
LEFT JOIN location ON computers.location = location.id
LEFT JOIN users ON computers.user_1 = users.id".
" ".$searchCriterias."
ORDER BY id
```

**WHERE:**

```
$searchCriterias =
    "WHERE 
        location.room_name LIKE '%".$s."%' OR
        users.user_name LIKE '%".$s."%'
    ";
```

`$s` is the string from the search form.

The thing is that I have computers.user_1, computers.user_2 and computers.user_3 that all corresponds to users.id as in the syntax above. When I search for a username I would like to match it with user_1, user_2 and user_3 but I don't get it to work. I can only match it with one (in this case user_1).

I have tried to add `LEFT JOIN users ON computers.user_2 = users.id` and gets this error message: Not unique table/alias: 'users'

and...

`LEFT JOIN users AS u1 ON computers.user_1 = users.id` for all three and gets this messge: Unknown column 'users.id' in 'on clause'.

Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Change WHERE to AND, and see about prepared statements - although I always struggle to understand the logic of OUTER JOINing a table on an OR condition where one alternative references the Other table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is to join against users 3 times, and amend your WHERE clause to check against 3 different tables.

Might need a DISTINCT to remove duplicates as I presume names can match multiple times.

This has the advantage over using an OR in the ON clause that it can still use indexes for the joins.

```
SELECT computers.*, location.room_name AS location
FROM computers
LEFT JOIN location ON computers.location = location.id
LEFT JOIN users users1 ON computers.user_1 = users1.id 
LEFT JOIN users users2 ON computers.user_2 = users2.id 
LEFT JOIN users users3 ON computers.user_3 = users3.id".
" ".$searchCriterias."
ORDER BY id
```

And the WHERE clause

```
$searchCriterias =
    "WHERE 
        location.room_name LIKE '%".$s."%' OR
        users1.user_name LIKE '%".$s."%' OR
        users2.user_name LIKE '%".$s."%' OR
        users3.user_name LIKE '%".$s."%'
    ";
```

Answer (score 1):

As you said you have 3 columns in `computers` table then try following while join. Also added `GROUP BY` to get unique result per user.

```
$query = "SELECT computers.*, location.room_name AS location
          FROM computers
          LEFT JOIN location ON computers.location = location.id
          LEFT JOIN users ON (computers.user_1 = users.id 
                   OR computers.user_2 = users.id 
                   OR computers.user_3 = users.id ) ".
          $searchCriterias . " GROUP BY users.id ORDER BY id";
```

Comment: This works fine for the search! But when $S is empty or not set (then $searchCriterias = "" and every post is printed) I get 2 or 3 of every post... Why?

Comment: @PoorCadaver I updated answer by adding `GROUP BY` clause for user id

Answer (score 1):

Change your ON condition to IN statement :

```
SELECT computers.*, location.room_name AS location
FROM computers
LEFT JOIN location ON computers.location = location.id
LEFT JOIN users
     ON ((users.id = computers.user_1) or
         (users.id =computer.user_2 and not exists(select 1 from users t where t.id = computers.user_1))  OR 
         (users.id = computer.user_3 AND not exists(select 1 from users p where p.id IN(computer.user_2,computer.user_1))))".
" ".$searchCriterias."
ORDER BY id
```

Comment: This works fine for the search! But when $S is empty or not set (then $searchCriterias = "" and every post is printed) I get 2 or 3 of every post... Why?

Comment: Yeah and it works great when I print the search results, but it should only show every post one time, not two or three when there is no WHEN-statement.

Comment: I want to search for "alex" and if there is a match in user_1, user_2 or user_3 I want to print that post - only one time.

Comment: @PoorCadaver Try it now.. not sure if I understood you

Comment: Its ok, you can still post here.. You can also delete previous comments @PoorCadaver

Comment: Ok! :) It still does the same thing though.

Comment: Ahh a typo , forgot the where .. now .. @PoorCadaver

Comment: Well... Now it shows the right amount of posts when I search and when all posts are shown, but it does not match with computers.user_2 or computers.user_3. It only searches in computers.user_1. :)

Comment: Sorry @sagi, just got a working alternative from Kickstart. Huge thank you for all your help though! :)